# How to upload a file from windows explorer pop up using squish automation tool

Tags: python, automation, squish

I am automating a web application using squish tool in python scripting. In a feature there is a file upload test scenario where I have to upload a file from the windows hard drive.

I have recorded the scenario but didn't get how to upload the file.
Can someone help me to resolve the problem

Comment: Please provide the code squish generated after you recorded it. Also provide the error or problem you encounter. Also ask a specific question! Do you use the squish for web version? Also see https://doc.froglogic.com/squish/latest/rgs-webconvenience.html#web-chooseFile-function

Comment: clickButton(waitForObject("UploadButtonLocator"))
setText(waitForObject(":AXIS Tool.file_c517cab9-6838-483a-ab39-178ce8e8812b_file"), "")

Comment: I am using Squish for web IDE

Comment: When you run the script, does a file dialog pop up? When you insert the path to the desired file into the "", does it work?

Comment: @frog.ca When I run the script , windows dialog is not even displayed. I have used the same API 'clickButton' which I get once I record the scenario. But even then it is not even popped up.

Comment: @Frieder Windows dialog is not even displayed when I click on the upload button.Click action is happening but window dialog is not displayed

Comment: It is generally expected that the file dialogs are being suppressed, because Squish for Web does not support them on as "objects". I recommend to contact Squish technical support to discuss this in detail, with more technical information about the setup and possibly a web page for reproducing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using nativeType() function to send file path and to hit enter key on the focused window (i.e. file open dialog)

Here is an example by [Squish](https://kb.froglogic.com/display/KB/Example+-+Automating+file+dialogs+with+type%28%29+and+nativeType%28%29)